# Android Rounded Line in Ad / Ad gaining focus

Tags: android, adsense

I've implemented Google Ad's in my app. The problem is: every time I touch the ad and go back to the application, a rounded line appears. It's like the ad gains focus.

A [picture](http://resources.reament.com/pictures/android.error.001.png) of the problem.

The ad code (that I'm merging in the app) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

        <com.google.ads.AdView
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                         
                         ads:adUnitId="a150203b883dd6d"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         android:focusable="false"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 39e0b3669eb01337"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</merge>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

could it be that the ad is rendered html in a webview?  if so, and you have access to the css being presented there edit it like so:

```
a {outline:0}
a:focus { outline:0;}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm not using any webview, I'm adding the component through the xml via merge/import.